# Operator such as $-1$ is the identity element

Tags: real-analysis

**Short question**
Do you know an operator such as $-1$ is the identity element ?

**Long Question**
This morning, I had a hard time with identity elements.
I'm pretty sure that the following isn't very rigourous, so please don't hesitate to comment !
I'm going to think in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, which means that $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are numbers like others real number. 
According to the addition, we can divide our real segment in two parts : $[-\infty, 0]$ and $[0, +\infty]$.
According to the multiplication, we can divide these two segments into four: $[-\infty, -1]$, $[-1, 0]$, $[0, 1]$ and $[1, +\infty]$.
So we can see $5$ key numbers : $-\infty, -1, 0, 1, \infty$.
The problem is that I can't find a function so that $-1$ is an identity element.
I hope the problem is not trivial ;)
We can picture the problem like that :
$$Function \to Identity\; element$$
$$max \to -\infty$$
$$??? \to -1$$
$$+ \to 0$$
$$\times \to 1$$
$$min \to \infty$$

Comment: $a \ast b = ab+2a+2b+2$

Comment: Why not just $x \star y = -xy$?

Comment: @Théophile, Indeed, you're right. Thanks ;)

Comment: Sorry that it turned out to be trivial. ;)

Comment: @MikeMiller, out of curiosity, how did you come up with your own answer?

Comment: @Théophile, Yeah ;) but it makes sense since $[-\infty, -1]$ is sent on $[0, 1]$ and $[-1, 0]$ is sent on $[1, \infty]$. The symmetry I was looking for is still there ;) Please write an answer to show that the question is solved

Comment: @Théophile Well, the multiplicative identity is $1$. Instead of negating like you did I shifted downwards: mine's just $(a+2)(b+2)-2$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks for the explanation. It's interesting to see how this generalizes in David's answer below.

Comment: @Théophile Looks like yours is a special case too, coming from $\phi(x)=-x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any bijection $\phi:{\Bbb R}\to{\Bbb R}$ and define an operation
$$x*y=\phi\bigl(\phi^{-1}(x)\phi^{-1}(y)\bigr)\ .$$
Then the identity element for $*$ is $\phi(1)$, which could be anything you like, depending on your choice of $\phi$.

In particular, the choice $\phi(x)=x-2$ gives the example from the comment by @MikeMiller.

You could do the same thing with addition:
$$x*y=\phi\bigl(\phi^{-1}(x)+\phi^{-1}(y)\bigr)\ .$$
and then the identity element would be $\phi(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the generalization ! Always a pleasure to read your answers.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this basically just means if we relabel the real numbers with the real numbers in some other way without changing the algebraic properties then of course whatever 1 gets relabeled as is the identity. The same could be said to be true of any set of the same cardinality.